# delete lines if firstline matches expression, but next 2 lines do not match different expression

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a test file in this format:

```
G03X22Y22.5
G01X48.5
M98P9001 (OFF)****
G00X20Y25
M98P8051 (FAST CUT)
G01X22Y34
G01X25Y33
```

I am trying to make a bash or MSDOS script that will :

Find all lines in the file that match : M98P9001

if the NEXT 2 LINES do not contain the code { M98P8050, M98P8080 OR M09 } Delete all 3 lines . which would result in the output :

```
G03X22Y22.5
G01X48.5
G01X22Y34
G01X25Y33
```

I've tried solutions with SED or AWK, but haven't gotten the right one yet:

```
sed -e '/M98P9001/,+2d' input.txt >> output.txt
```

this one will always delete all 3 lines after finding the match , but I need to only delete the lines if the next 2 lines following the match do not have a match with { M98P8050, M98P8080 OR M09 }.

Comment: Does `M98P90012345` "match" `M98P9001` or not? SImilarly for all of the strings you want to match - are you looking for partial matches or full work matches or something else?

Comment: Do both subsequent lines have to match or just 1 of them?

Answer (score 2):

a mark and sweep approach

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {if(!(/M98P80[58]0|M09/ && p~/M98P80[58]0|M09/) && pp~/M98P9001/)
                 {a[NR]; a[NR-1]; a[NR-2]} 
                pp=p; p=$0; next} 
       !(FNR in a)' file{,}


G03X22Y22.5
G01X48.5
G01X22Y34
G01X25Y33
```

Comment: It's not clear from the question if `M09` should match `M09P123`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to give your desired output:

```
awk '
  /M98P9001/ { 
    getline l2; getline l3;
    if((l2 l3)~/M98P8050|M98P8080|M09/) printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n", $0, l2, l3; 
    next; 
  } 
  { print; }'
```

Description:

- If first line pattern match, read in next two lines to variables.
- Check concatenation of both lines for any of the 3 secondary patterns
- If match, print all three lines, else print nothing.
- go to next record.
- on all other lines, print.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;N;s/\n/&/2;Ta;/^[^\n]*M98P9001/{/\n.*(M98P8050|M98P8080|M09)/!d};P;D' file
```

Open a three line window throughout the length of the file.

If the first line of the window contains `M98P9001` and either of the second or third lines do not contain `M98P8050`, `M98P8080` or `M09` delete the entire window and repeat.

Otherwise, print/delete the first line of the window and repeat.

N.B. The idiom `:a;N;s/\n/&/2;Ta` tops up the three line window.